# Using a variable after if statement

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

Wondering what is faster and/or what is better practice when checking a variable in an if statement and then using it again after the if statement.

Like

```
if var_A + var_B > 10:
    var_C = var_A + var_B
```

or

```
 var_temp = var_A + var_B
 if var_temp > 10:
           var_C = var_temp
```

sorry for the bad examples, was just wonder which of these is better

Comment: Would `var_C` be set to anything else if the test failed? Or is it left unbound?

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the second version is better:

- It's faster. The expression is calculated only once.
- It's easier to refactor. You will change the expression only in one place.
- It's more readable. The temporary variable name can tell the meaning of the expression.

Comment: What if the temp var is a very large string or it gets called allot does it create allot of temp variables in memory or do they get cleaned quick? sorry for not having a concrete question or example, im just wondering how it works

Comment: `temp_var` and `var_C` refer to the same object, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Tricky if you don't store the expression result in a variable it gets garbage collected after the comparison and then again created under a different reference.

Answer (score 3):

The third option, my favorite, would be to set it and check for untruthy to set `var_C` to some fallback

```
var_C = var_A + var_B
if var_C <= 10:
    var_C = None
```

no extra variable needed

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is the best. Subjectively speaking, it's much easier for the next guy to read and maintain.